# Incorrect CRC calculation in protocol. One is implemented using zlib and the other one is calculated in function

Tags: python, c, stm32, zlib, crc

I am implementing a protocol in an STM32F412 board. It's almost done, I just need to do a CRC check for the received data.

I tried using the internal CRC module for calculating the CRC but I could not match the result to any online CRC algorithm online, so I decided to do a simple implementation of the Ethernet CRC.

```
static const uint32_t crc32_tab[] =
{
    0x00000000L, 0x77073096L, 0xee0e612cL, 0x990951baL, 0x076dc419L,
    0x706af48fL, 0xe963a535L, 0x9e6495a3L, 0x0edb8832L, 0x79dcb8a4L,
    0xe0d5e91eL, 0x97d2d988L, 0x09b64c2bL, 0x7eb17cbdL, 0xe7b82d07L,
    0x90bf1d91L, 0x1db71064L, 0x6ab020f2L, 0xf3b97148L, 0x84be41deL,
    0x1adad47dL, 0x6ddde4ebL, 0xf4d4b551L, 0x83d385c7L, 0x136c9856L,
    0x646ba8c0L, 0xfd62f97aL, 0x8a65c9ecL, 0x14015c4fL, 0x63066cd9L,
    0xfa0f3d63L, 0x8d080df5L, 0x3b6e20c8L, 0x4c69105eL, 0xd56041e4L,
    0xa2677172L, 0x3c03e4d1L, 0x4b04d447L, 0xd20d85fdL, 0xa50ab56bL,
    0x35b5a8faL, 0x42b2986cL, 0xdbbbc9d6L, 0xacbcf940L, 0x32d86ce3L,
    0x45df5c75L, 0xdcd60dcfL, 0xabd13d59L, 0x26d930acL, 0x51de003aL,
    0xc8d75180L, 0xbfd06116L, 0x21b4f4b5L, 0x56b3c423L, 0xcfba9599L,
    0xb8bda50fL, 0x2802b89eL, 0x5f058808L, 0xc60cd9b2L, 0xb10be924L,
    0x2f6f7c87L, 0x58684c11L, 0xc1611dabL, 0xb6662d3dL, 0x76dc4190L,
    0x01db7106L, 0x98d220bcL, 0xefd5102aL, 0x71b18589L, 0x06b6b51fL,
    0x9fbfe4a5L, 0xe8b8d433L, 0x7807c9a2L, 0x0f00f934L, 0x9609a88eL,
    0xe10e9818L, 0x7f6a0dbbL, 0x086d3d2dL, 0x91646c97L, 0xe6635c01L,
    0x6b6b51f4L, 0x1c6c6162L, 0x856530d8L, 0xf262004eL, 0x6c0695edL,
    0x1b01a57bL, 0x8208f4c1L, 0xf50fc457L, 0x65b0d9c6L, 0x12b7e950L,
    0x8bbeb8eaL, 0xfcb9887cL, 0x62dd1ddfL, 0x15da2d49L, 0x8cd37cf3L,
    0xfbd44c65L, 0x4db26158L, 0x3ab551ceL, 0xa3bc0074L, 0xd4bb30e2L,
    0x4adfa541L, 0x3dd895d7L, 0xa4d1c46dL, 0xd3d6f4fbL, 0x4369e96aL,
    0x346ed9fcL, 0xad678846L, 0xda60b8d0L, 0x44042d73L, 0x33031de5L,
    0xaa0a4c5fL, 0xdd0d7cc9L, 0x5005713cL, 0x270241aaL, 0xbe0b1010L,
    0xc90c2086L, 0x5768b525L, 0x206f85b3L, 0xb966d409L, 0xce61e49fL,
    0x5edef90eL, 0x29d9c998L, 0xb0d09822L, 0xc7d7a8b4L, 0x59b33d17L,
    0x2eb40d81L, 0xb7bd5c3bL, 0xc0ba6cadL, 0xedb88320L, 0x9abfb3b6L,
    0x03b6e20cL, 0x74b1d29aL, 0xead54739L, 0x9dd277afL, 0x04db2615L,
    0x73dc1683L, 0xe3630b12L, 0x94643b84L, 0x0d6d6a3eL, 0x7a6a5aa8L,
    0xe40ecf0bL, 0x9309ff9dL, 0x0a00ae27L, 0x7d079eb1L, 0xf00f9344L,
    0x8708a3d2L, 0x1e01f268L, 0x6906c2feL, 0xf762575dL, 0x806567cbL,
    0x196c3671L, 0x6e6b06e7L, 0xfed41b76L, 0x89d32be0L, 0x10da7a5aL,
    0x67dd4accL, 0xf9b9df6fL, 0x8ebeeff9L, 0x17b7be43L, 0x60b08ed5L,
    0xd6d6a3e8L, 0xa1d1937eL, 0x38d8c2c4L, 0x4fdff252L, 0xd1bb67f1L,
    0xa6bc5767L, 0x3fb506ddL, 0x48b2364bL, 0xd80d2bdaL, 0xaf0a1b4cL,
    0x36034af6L, 0x41047a60L, 0xdf60efc3L, 0xa867df55L, 0x316e8eefL,
    0x4669be79L, 0xcb61b38cL, 0xbc66831aL, 0x256fd2a0L, 0x5268e236L,
    0xcc0c7795L, 0xbb0b4703L, 0x220216b9L, 0x5505262fL, 0xc5ba3bbeL,
    0xb2bd0b28L, 0x2bb45a92L, 0x5cb36a04L, 0xc2d7ffa7L, 0xb5d0cf31L,
    0x2cd99e8bL, 0x5bdeae1dL, 0x9b64c2b0L, 0xec63f226L, 0x756aa39cL,
    0x026d930aL, 0x9c0906a9L, 0xeb0e363fL, 0x72076785L, 0x05005713L,
    0x95bf4a82L, 0xe2b87a14L, 0x7bb12baeL, 0x0cb61b38L, 0x92d28e9bL,
    0xe5d5be0dL, 0x7cdcefb7L, 0x0bdbdf21L, 0x86d3d2d4L, 0xf1d4e242L,
    0x68ddb3f8L, 0x1fda836eL, 0x81be16cdL, 0xf6b9265bL, 0x6fb077e1L,
    0x18b74777L, 0x88085ae6L, 0xff0f6a70L, 0x66063bcaL, 0x11010b5cL,
    0x8f659effL, 0xf862ae69L, 0x616bffd3L, 0x166ccf45L, 0xa00ae278L,
    0xd70dd2eeL, 0x4e048354L, 0x3903b3c2L, 0xa7672661L, 0xd06016f7L,
    0x4969474dL, 0x3e6e77dbL, 0xaed16a4aL, 0xd9d65adcL, 0x40df0b66L,
    0x37d83bf0L, 0xa9bcae53L, 0xdebb9ec5L, 0x47b2cf7fL, 0x30b5ffe9L,
    0xbdbdf21cL, 0xcabac28aL, 0x53b39330L, 0x24b4a3a6L, 0xbad03605L,
    0xcdd70693L, 0x54de5729L, 0x23d967bfL, 0xb3667a2eL, 0xc4614ab8L,
    0x5d681b02L, 0x2a6f2b94L, 0xb40bbe37L, 0xc30c8ea1L, 0x5a05df1bL,
    0x2d02ef8dL
};

uint32_t calc_crc_calculate(uint8_t *pData, uint32_t uLen)
{
    uint32_t val = 0xFFFFFFFFU;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < uLen; i++) {
        val = crc32_tab[(val ^ pData[i]) & 0xFF] ^ ((val >> 8) & 0x00FFFFFF);
    }

    return val^0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

I calculated the crc of 0x6F and compared the result to the online calculators and it apparently matches.

When I try to test the protocol with my python code I'm just unable to match the CRCs. On python I'm using the following code:

```
d = 0x6f
crc = zlib.crc32(bytes(d))&0xFFFFFFFF
```

I'm now unable to tell which is right. Apparently my algorithm is OK because it matches the online calculator. **BUT** those online calculators do not seem to be reliable sometimes and I doubt that python's zlib implementation is wrong .. I may be using it wrong at worst.

Comment: *What* are the results you are getting from both?

Comment: BTW, I have a feeling that `bytes(d)` is not giving what you think it is... Try printing it.

Comment: [bytes()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/bytes) with integer parameter will five you array of bytes of this length initialized to zeros. VTC as not reproducible...

Comment: @EugeneSh. 0xf0f9344 with the C code and 0xb062b673 using python's zlib. I actually fixed my error now. I was just doing something wrong with my python code. Exactly what you are saying ... bytes(d) was my problem

Comment: Aside: the `L` in `crc32_tab[]` constants is not needed - for the same reason `0x00FFFFFF` is OK without an `L`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can compute the Ethernet CRC32 with the builtin module of the STM32. It took me quite a while to make it match up as well.

This code should match up for sizes divisible by 4 (I also used python zlib on the other end):

```
#include "stm32l4xx_hal.h"

uint32_t CRC32_Compute(const uint32_t *data, size_t sizeIn32BitWords)
{
  CRC_HandleTypeDef hcrc = {
    .Instance = CRC,
    .Init.DefaultPolynomialUse = DEFAULT_POLYNOMIAL_ENABLE,
    .Init.DefaultInitValueUse = DEFAULT_INIT_VALUE_ENABLE,
    .Init.InputDataInversionMode = CRC_INPUTDATA_INVERSION_WORD,
    .Init.OutputDataInversionMode = CRC_OUTPUTDATA_INVERSION_ENABLE,
    .InputDataFormat = CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_WORDS,
  };
  HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_CRC_Init(&hcrc);
  assert (status == HAL_OK)
  uint32_t checksum =  HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc, data, sizeIn32BitWords);

  uint32_t checksumInverted = ~checksum;
  return checksumInverted;
}
```

The challenge with sizes not divisible by 4 is to get the "inversion/reversal" (changing the bit order) right. There is an example how the hardware handles this in the "RM0394 Reference manual STM32L43xxx STM32L44xxx STM32L45xxx STM32L46xxx advanced ARM®-based 32-bit MCUs Rev 3" on page 333.
The essence is that reversal reverses the bit order. For CRC32 this reversal must happen on the word level, i.e. over 32 bits.

Comment: I tried doing that. But it gave me the incorrect result. I used the known CRC of a value and it would refuse a correct result. The problem might be that I was doing a CRC of 1 byte ... i'd probably have to fill it with zeros when there is no more data ... I'll try it later

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It certainly was a bug on my part. But it was happening in my python code.

I suddenly realized that I was practically doing bytes(0x6F) which just creates an array with 111 positions.

What I actually needed to do was

```
import struct

d = pack('B', 0x6F)
crc = zlib.crc32(bytes(d))&0xFFFFFFFF
```

This question could have been avoided had I just done a little bit of rubber duck debugging. Hopefuly this will help someone else.